# Does someone know why the Chromium daily package isn't build anymore?

Tags: ppa, chromium

It looks like chromium-browser @ https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa haven't been build for the past 6 weeks.

I tried to get in touch with them on launchpad but I've got no answers...

Comment: The daily and Dev channels have stopped, probably because at the Beta channel the  last build there which is 2 weeks old, completely failed to build on various of its components.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, the machine that the bot was running on was low on disk space (which preparing chromium uploads requires quite a bit).  I was going to try to do some manual uploads for the beta and dev channels.  I'm not sure how soon the dailies will be available again.  I can try to post here when the space issues are resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and for taking care of packaging it!

Comment: Hurray build looks fixed :) Any plan on releasing on precise?

Comment: Not exactly fixed yet, I've copied the latest version (which is currently the stable/beta 18.0.1025.151) to all the PPAs as it's higher that what's there.  Still working on get this automated again.

Comment: **micahg**, is almost 2 months since your last message. Is there any news?

Comment: Still no update, seems the _chromium-daily_ PPAs have been abandoned.

Comment: not abandoned, but on hold

Comment: @micahg, Could you please state this at the PPAs' pages? Someone could go there and think it's abandoned, like I did before read this answer.

Comment: Wait a second. Why not use recepies to build from git?

Comment: @Amith could you share such a recipe and

Comment: @micahg what specs do you need for the machine, maybe I can share one.

Answer (score 4):

@micahg answers this question. In the meantime, my current workaround is to install a more recent chromium from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview). You can add-apt-repository and install it as usual.  I didn't want the other packages from the repository so I pinned just the chromium packages to prevent the rest from installing.  Wrote a step by step [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170265/28944).  There is also  another repository that has a new chromium mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/163046/28944) and fewer other packages so you won't need to pin packages, but the developer hosting that package currently is dissuading people from using it, hence my preference for the former repository.

I hope at some point we have a more unified "definitive" place to get chromium rather than these disparate repositories, like it used to be with the chromium-daily channel which they are trying to get going again.

Comment: You should link this question to yours or ask a moderator for it instead of the answer you put.

Comment: I just edited my answer to mention another question besides mine, so can't really link it just to that one as users might prefer the latter repository (which doesn't require pinning).

Comment: There are inofficial PPAs for the Chromium [stable](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium) and [dev](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium-dev) channels.