# What happened to the Ubuntu Chromium project?

Tags: 12.04, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does someone know why the Chromium daily package isn't build anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore)

What has happened to the Ubuntu Chromium project at https://launchpad.net/chromium-project? There are no builds for Ubuntu 12.04 and the latest version available there is version 18 (For ALL channels, even nightly). But the current stable version of Chrome is version 20 and the latest available development version is version 22.

In the past this PPA provided a new Chromium package shortly after Google released a new Chrome version. But now the stable channel is two versions behind and nightly is even four versions behind.

Is this project dead? Is there a replacement PPA? Or maybe some automatic build job is broken and nobody noticed it yet?