# Google Chrome not rendering webpages correctly

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, javascript

I am facing some serious web page rendering issues with Chrome.
It is more prominent during javascript based animations and stuff on websites like youtube.
I have tried removing chrome using (sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable) and then reinstalling it. But the problems still persist.
The same webpages work correctly on firefox on ubuntu and chrome on windows. The problem only shows up when I use chrome on ubuntu.

I think the issue has started after I updated to the latest version of Chrome. I have used Chrome previously on this machine without any problems.

I have attached a image that demonstrates the issue.

[image]

What could possibly be the problem?

PS: here's the output of lshw -c video:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]
   vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0000000-f001ffff
```

Here's the output of lspci -nn:
[output of lspci -nn](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1082424/)

Comment: Merely removing and reinstalling may not help if your profile is corrupted. You may need to remove your profile. It's often more likely that a problem with your profile or the extensions therein are responsible. Go through [Create a new browser user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059).

Comment: are you using some addon?

Comment: @Web-E: using a couple of extensions from google: Chat for google, Google mail checker 3.2, Google Reader notifier 1.3.1, Google Tasks 1.0, Google + notifications. Mostly stuff from the Chrome store.

Comment: Try **incognito Mode** , and see if its still persists.

Comment: @tijybba: still exists in incognito mode. Tried it.

Comment: Do you have any Graphics Driver installed and if it is which Model. Then paste the output of `sudo lshw -short`

Comment: @tijybba: here's the output:
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0000000-f001ffff

Comment: Post it in question by editing it so others may see it easily.

Comment: @vasa1: I tried creating a new profile. Didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue was with the **graphic drivers**.

I downloaded and installed the latest driver from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)
and now everything looks fine.

Thanks to @tijybba.

Comment: I was having this problem as well on two different computers (one laptop, one desktop) both with an ATI card. Updating from the driver that ships with Ubuntu (8.960) to the latest from the link above (8.982) solved the problem. I'm actually surprised more people aren't having this issue.

Comment: @sumit_gt I also seem to have the tearing issues. Alas my HD4870 video card is considered legacy now, and the latest video driver supported is 12.6. The driver itself runs fine, I even play games on Steam in Ubuntu. Same pages render correctly in Firefox, but run like crap in Chrome.

Comment: I'm with the same issue with native intel drivers... most commonly in GMail...

Answer (score 8):

For me, this helped:

1. Download latest beta drivers from AMD website.
2. Uninstall ATI drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
   ```
3. Reinstall xorg:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon
   ```
4. Reboot.
5. Install new beta drivers:

   ```
   sudo sh beta_drivers_name.run
   ```
6. Reboot and Chrome works fine.
7. Remove "AMD testing use only" logo (optional):
   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076381

Comment: i face this issue too. i ll try to install latest beta drivers, and i hope their beta drivers do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem by enabling the "**tear free**" option on the Catalyst Control Center:

> System Tools → Preferences → AMD Catalyst Control Center → Display Options → Tear Free

Comment: Slows down graphics very hard, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a ppa build of Chromium instead of Google Chrome? There is a ppa for it [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/chromium_stable_channel/precise/main/base/chromium-browser).The latest development builds are [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=unstable_amd64_deb).
These builds are meant to be the same as Google Chrome Canary, the experimental version of Chrome, that has great HTML5 support, but without some plugins, such as PDF, Flash, FFMpeg.

Comment: I voted this down because it doesn't attempt to answer the question. Plus, it refers to a ppa that is currently offering a significantly older version of Chromium.

Comment: The reason I mentioned Google Chrome Canary is that many Chrome users haven't heard of it. If they knew about it, they might want to try it instead. I have updated the link - thanks for spotting that. You have a good eye!

Comment: Even the updated link currently points to Chromium 18 whereas Chrome stable is presently version 20. Anyway, you may want to see this question about the [Chromium ppa](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159483/what-happened-to-the-ubuntu-chromium-project). As far as Canary goes, it may not be a good idea to recommend it unless a person wants to use a bleeding edge browser and, AFAIK, there are [no Canary builds for Linux](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to java scripting. A good example is the website www.nasa.gov. If you look at it using firefox it renders ok. Chrome does not seem to work correctly. Especially the script displaying scrolling pictures (in a jQuery tupe of fashion) dails. Other websites have problems in rendering forms correctly (e.g. you can't fill in name fields for instance).

Might it be related to the fact that those websites have a HTML4 header but in fact use html5 technology?

Comment: Nope, that is not the issue. I have mentioned in the question that the same webpages render correctly in  Chrome on Windows. Also, I hardly think pages like YouTube would make mistakes in javascripting....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same tearing problem as well as popping during audio playback with a Radeon HD 3450 after upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04.  I tried the latest drivers from Ubuntu and ATI, and neither one worked, I think because it's now a "legacy" product.  I couldn't enable Tear Free Desktop because I got an "insufficient graphics adapter memory" error.

This is what fixed it for me:

1. Enable Canonical partner repository
   https://askubuntu.com/a/14633/18665
2. Install Flash from Adobe
   `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`
3. In Chrome, browse to chrome://plugins/
4. In the upper right side of the screen, click the + next to Details
5. Scroll down to Adobe Flash Player, find the version with PepperFlash in the path, and click Disable

Answer (score 0):

I had a kind of similar problem:
certain webpages didn't loaded or took them a long time to load.
of them was google.co.uk webpage.
I went to the extensions and removed "Hola better internet" extension.
My Chrome is superfast now.

Cheers