# How to fix facebook,Youtube problems in chrome with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome

Hey guys after installing ubuntu 12.04 I faced several problems with My Graphics card.  Folowing this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx):  I was able to install my Catalyst and everything seems OK. The only problem I have is Chrome. Facebook, Youtube and maybe other sites are messed up.[image].  I checked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161450/google-chrome-not-rendering-webpages-correctly) too  but, I have already installed the correct drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary workaround that worked for me is to disable the PepperFlash plugin in Google Chrome.

1. Type chrome://plugins in your address bar.
2. Disable the PepperFlash plugin as shown in the screenshot below.
   [image: Disable PepperFlash]
3. Restart Google Chrome

After this, all of my Facebook and YouTube rendering issues disappeared. But I would keep checking the question you mentioned, and keep your graphics card driver updated.

Source: http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/07/how-to-fix-rendering-issues-in-google.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply but, I switched to linux Opensuse and it work perfect for me. It is better than Ubuntu.

Comment: @Adio Could you please mark this as the answer that solved the issue then? Thank you.