# Chrome Screen Tearing while rendering pages

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, video, google-chrome

I know my question might be close to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161450/google-chrome-not-rendering-webpages-correctly), but for me none of the solution fixed the issue completely, although one has improved the situation a bit.

Simply put, I have rendering problems on Chrome on pages what seem to use latest fancy flash and other eye-candy (youtube.com among them) stuff. I am experiencing vertical tearing.

Some examples:

[image: text tearing]
[image: image tearing]

What I have:

OS: **Ubuntu 12.04**

Video Card: **AMD HD4870** (still a beast of a card as it runs most new games on high end on high rezolution)

Video Driver: ATI Catalyst official **12.06** (as my video card is considered legacy nowadays, that's the driver to go. Installing the latest 12.10 driver renders me an error of card not supported).

Output of `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV770 [Radeon HD 4870]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe7e0000-fe7effff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:fe7c0000-fe7dffff
```

I have this issues only since I installed the official AMD drivers. Until then I was using the default mesa drivers, and everything was working as a peach. But then Steam came to Linux, and I just had to jump on it. Now my games run smoothly under Ubuntu with Steam, but I have this tearing issues in Chrome.

Ahh, by the way, on Firefox there are no issues.

From the above mentioned post, I have enabled the **"tear free"** option, and that seemed to reduce the problem a bit, but still didn't eliminate it.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Edit:

Going to chrome://plugins/ at the flash-player section I have to following:

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything in chrome://flags tweaked, especially relating to rendering/hardware acceleration? You might want to look there, it some of the flags could cause rendering problems.

Comment: To my knowledge I haven't touched that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problems, seems that the new Pepper Flash version included by default with Chrome doesn't play well with AMD cards. I haven't found a good way to solve it yet, but a workaround is to just use the normal flash player included by Ubuntu instead.

To do that, go to chrome://plugins

- On the right side of the screen, click on "Details" if neccasery.
- Search for the Adobe Flash Player plugin and disable the PPAPI (pepper) plugin, leaving the other one enabled.
- Restart the browser to apply the changes.

EDIT: Screenshot of what I mean[image: Screenshot of Flash settings]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried with both  combinations: PepperFlash disabled and adobe-flashplugin disabled and with Pepper disabled and adobe-flashplugin enabled and the tearing is still there. :( Which one is the "other one" for you?

Comment: The working combination for me is Pepper Flash disabled (Right now version 11.5) and the adobe flash plugin (version 11.2) enabled. Make sure to restart the browser too!

Comment: I've added in my question the plugins I have for adobe flash player

Comment: As my edit demonstrates I have the same combo. I am testing with this link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/cnn-predict-ubuntu-phone-wont-make-inroads Try to scroll through it.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my setup.

Comment: Hm, in that case, I am not sure, I am sorry.. :/ As far as I know it's a problem with the AMD drivers, but I haven't been able to find a proper fix yet..

Comment: I had to use google translate from Dutch to make sure which one is Enabled and which one Disabled :) only to find out that I had them the other way around. But still, for this particular site the issue is still there. Thanks for your help. I'll leave this question around for a while, maybe somebody has an idea. +1 for the effort mate.

Comment: Alright, thanks and good luck! I upvoted your question so hopefully someone else is able to help you further! :)

Comment: Now after several restarts I have noticed that the tearing has disappeared. So, thanks again, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

sorry to pop in on this so late. However I was also encountering the issue today and stumbled upon this. What fixed it for me was going to chrome://flags and enabling "Override software rendering list Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Overrides the built-in software rendering list and enables GPU-acceleration on unsupported system configurations"

I guess for some reason for me 2D hw accel wasn't working.

Just adding this here in case anyone else ever has this issue.

Kind Regards,
openSUSE user

Comment: That did not work in Chrome 53 on Kubuntu 16.04.1, KDE 5.6.5. Chrome shows horizontal tearing even when scrolling [text-only parts of Wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax).