# How can I fix screen tearing in google chrome?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I have tried everything, from changing smooth in scrolling chrome://flags to updating drivers. Currently running ubuntu 16.04, and I only get screen tearing in google chrome whether it's watching youtube videos or casually browsing the internet...

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot for the screen tearing?

Comment: Ito not constant, it's only when I am scrolling through the browsers and watching videos now, it's almost like it flickers on and off john400

Comment: Have you tried this one out.http://askubuntu.com/questions/237881/chrome-screen-tearing-while-rendering-pages?rq=1

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Just to demonstrate, [here](https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/376907Screenshotfrom20170730122641.png) is a screenshot. Ironically,  it demonstrates the problem on this very page.

Comment: Do you have hardware acceleration enabled in Chrome?

Comment: If you still have this issue please [edit] your post to include the output of  `sudo lshw -C display` and if not, please share your solution with the community. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

screen tearing probably is mostly graphic card issue.

if you use nvidia,
you can try :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGdX6.png)

Load "nvidia-settings"(see screenshot) and you will need to go to this screen and then hit “Advanced” at the bottom (my screenshot doesn't have the button, as this is what you see after you hit it).
Tick the boxes for “Force Composition Pipeline” and “Force Full Composition Pipeline” and then hit "Apply".
Then you can then enjoy a tear-free experience on Linux with an NVIDIA GPU.

make sure you update to latest graphic driver by adding this repo in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
```

---

also, it's better to post your system configuration before posting to help getting accurate answer by running in terminal:

```
inxi -Fxxrzc0
```

and paste the result to gist or pastebin.

hope this helps.