# Severe screen tearing on Chrome without any proprietary graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, google-chrome

I am experiencing some severe screen tearing on Chrome on 16.04. My PC has an AMD APU (A4-3400 with Radeon HD 6000 graphics) and I am not able to install proprietary drivers for it because it causes the login screen to reset, so I prefer to stick with open-source drivers.

I tried to turn-off hardware acceleration, which was indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237881/chrome-screen-tearing-while-rendering-pages)

`sudo lshw -c video` output:
`description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sumo [Radeon HD 6410D]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fef00000-fef3ffff memory:c0000-dffff`

Comment: I don't think the AMD drivers have been ported over to 16.04 and I think the open source drivers are not the best. My genuine advice would be to install an nvidia card and don't look back. Failing that, take a look at using Compton as your compositor, I have had pretty good results regarding screen tearing with it.

Comment: The latest driver version for my APU was 15.9 and, YES, it is NOT been ported to 16.04 LTS as they are only available for 12.04.4 LTS and 14.04.2.

Comment: ... And I don't think also that my CPU can bottleneck a GT 1030 or GT 730.

Answer (score 0):

### I have three suggestions for you:

#### Install updated open source video drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
```

This will update open source video AMD driver to more recent version and install CPU microcode

#### Disable DRI3 acceleration for Chromium based browsers

```
echo 'export LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1' >> ~/.profile
# restart after doing this
```

#### Try the most recent optimized kernel from [XanMod](https://xanmod.org/)

```
echo 'deb http://deb.xanmod.org releases main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xanmod-kernel.list
wget -qO - http://deb.xanmod.org/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-xanmod-4.11
```

Comment: Disabling DRI3 acceleration dosen't help. I am not able to update the microcode since our Internet speed here in the Philippines is very, very slow.

Comment: Linux without internet is just something impossible. The only major distribution that has complete set of packages on DVD is CentOS.