# Facebook issue in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome not rendering webpages correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161450/google-chrome-not-rendering-webpages-correctly)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Google Chrome version 23.0.1271.97. My Facebook chat bar is not rendering properly. When I scroll down my news feed the chat bar appears distorted.

[image: Click here]

I have cleared the cache, and the problem still persists.

Comment: I do not think this is an Ubuntu issue or Chrome issue. Most likely a Facebook issue, maybe along the lines of "Facebook! stop changing the site so many times!!". This is also happening to me and even on Windows systems and other browsers.

Comment: Similar to [Google Chrome not rendering webpages correctly](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161450/google-chrome-not-rendering-webpages-correctly).

Comment: Remember `Google Chrome` is not on Ubuntu repositories, thus it is not officially supported. Why not use the `Chromium` instead? It is basically the same browser, but it works perfectly on Ubuntu and it *is* supported. Find it on Software Center!

Comment: @MestreLion Chrome's not part of Ubuntu (not provided in Ubuntu's official repositories). But we **do** support Chrome on Ubuntu here. (["We welcome questions about: ...Running third-party applications on Ubuntu."](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)) I prefer Chromium also (it's FOSS), and am using it right now, but  some prefer Chrome--it is updated more quickly (sometimes Chromium in Ubuntu lags behind considerably even when there are security vulnerabilities), and Chrome [has more features](http://askubuntu.com/q/6253). There's no reason either would work "perfectly."

Comment: @EliahKagan: by *"not officially supported"* I meant not supported by Ubuntu/Canonical, since it is a 3rd party software. Thank you for clarifying that those are still accepted *here* on AskUbuntu. As for Chrome's *"more features"* it is worth mentioning that these features are also available in Chromium once you install the corresponding codecs/flash packages in Software Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into that problem as well. The way I solved it was by clearing out my application data and installing a beta version of Chrome. If you're having the same problem I used to have, try going to YouTube and clicking the "Show More" button for a video - it wouldn't render properly.

To clear chrome's application data, first make sure Chrome is not running (open this webpage in Firefox or something else). We're going to be backing up the data just in case something goes awry. Open up a terminal and run this command: `mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.bkup`.

Try using Google Chrome and seeing if the problem persists.  Don't worry, your bookmarks and things are safe in that backup or in the cloud if you're using Google Synchronization.

If the problem still persists, we can try installing the Google Chrome Beta. Google Chrome continually has three releases at a time: stable, beta, and development. Stable is designed for the general public, beta is for people who want a sneak peek at new features, and development is for people who want to live on the edge. I'm on the development version right now. The beta may have fixed the problem you are having.

Simply run these commands to remove the stable version and install the beta (make sure Chrome is closed first!)

`sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta`