# Why Firefox always gets upgraded and Chromium web browser don't?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

Why Firefox always gets upgraded to the latest version available and Chromium web browser don't get upgraded to the latest version available? they are both open source software. 
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox version at this moment is 36.0.1 but Chromium version is stuck at 37.0.2062.120 although latest Chrome version available at the moment is 41.0.2272.76. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The given problem was addressed in a similar post. Here is the link:

[Why is Chromium not updated automatically as Firefox is?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166931/why-is-chromium-not-updated-automatically-as-firefox-is)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a newer version of Ubuntu you'd be on Chromium 41.  However, precise (Ubuntu 12.04) is on a branch of Chromium 37.

For maintaining a stable Ubuntu release, the preference is for it to be released with software at a given version and for that software to stay at that version for that release - that is, not to be updated, except to fix bugs or security issues but stay at the same main version number.

It is Firefox, in this case, that has the unusual release strategy.  With Firefox, the Ubuntu devs have decided that it's not feasible/preferable to continue to fix bugs in an older version of Firefox so they update to newer versions of Firefox.  In Chromium, by contrast, they appear to be happy for the precise (old LTS) release to continue to support Chromium 37 with patches for the time being.