# why does Chromium show version 18 even after an update?

Tags: 12.04, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does someone know why the Chromium daily package isn't build anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore)

I updated Chromium in 12.04 with apt-get from the official repositories and `chromium-browser --version` say `Chromium 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04`. but "About Chromium" from the browser itself say `18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04`

why is that ? 
how can I update Chromium ?

Comment: did Chromium forget to update the about section?

Comment: I don't this it's a duplicate. [There was an update](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/updates/chromium-browser).

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser` then `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and then try again.

Comment: it still shows version 18 in the browser and 20 in the command line --version

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs