# Can someone explain why Chromium is difficult to build for Ubuntu?

Tags: chromium

I hope this question is not regarded as a duplicate of [Does someone know why the Chromium daily package isn't build anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore) because that question relates to **daily builds** and not to "stable" Chromium available from the Software Center.

So what are the technical difficulties that the Chromium team is facing? A very similar question has been asked in [Default Browser Follow-up](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2013-June/004250.html). I would very much to have an updated Chromium stable on my system.

Also, is the problem of building Chromium restricted to 32-bit versions? (I have a 64-bit CPU but just 4 GB RAM and so I'm staying with 32-bit all the way.)

<sup>I'm asking this partly in the light of the discussions, [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/ubuntu-developer-continue-to-mull-switch-to-chromium) for example, about having Chromium as the default web browser in future releases.</sup>

Comment: Since your question is already several months old: Have you gone through the process of building chromium on Ubuntu? I'm considering doing this myself since there's no regularly updated PPA for chromium. But first I'll need to get more RAM it seems. At least 8GB is recommended. Not sure what the exact technical difficulties are, but I guess it can be quite frustrating when building chrome takes [100+ hours](https://twitter.com/chadmiller/status/387201160832364544) and then fail.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, I haven't tried to build Chromium, ever. I was curious and hoped that someone could explain why it's diffcult. Even now, [Chromium - Stable Channel](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/stable) has v29 when Google Chrome 30 went "stable" on 20131001.