# How do I install the latest version of Chromium in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, ppa, chromium

Previously [this same question was asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/89058/29097), however *all* of the answers are wrong -- including the chosen one. So, let's try it again. (I've specified the Ubuntu version number at the top to indicate the newness of this one). I'm coming at this as someone who has just installed Ubuntu and truly wants the latest version of Chromium.

Currently, the most recent version of Chromium is **Version 30**.

### **PPAs that don't work and should not be suggested**:

1. `ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium`

   As of writing, this PPA only supports [version 25 in stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium) and [version 27 in dev](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium-dev). It hasn't been updated in three months.
2. [`ppa:chromium-daily/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Echromium-daily/+archive/ppa)

   As of writing, this PPA only supports [version 18](https://launchpad.net/%7Echromium-daily/+archive/ppa). This PPA is so outdated  that I've submitted a [bug report suggesting it be shut down](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1198529).
3. [`ppa:webapps/preview`](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebapps/+archive/preview)

   As of writing, this PPA only supports [version 20](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebapps/+archive/preview). It hasn't been updated in 11 months.

Comment: I want to be clear -- I'm speaking rhetorically in this question. I'm not an Ubuntu newbie. I'm actually going to build it from source in a few minutes, but I think the question should be on askubuntu.com, even if there is no answer because the demand has not been met with an official ppa or upgrade script.

Comment: Technically the latest stable for Ubuntu is the one in the repositories >:-D Anything else is considered unstable...

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the correct parlance or not. I've never heard of production releases outside of the freeze-date as "unstable." But, the question has been modified to resolve any potential ambiguity.

Comment: This is the best I can find: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question. Do let us know how your attempts at building it went. From what I understand, building Chromium for Linux is far from a trivial task. It's one of the reasons Google doesn't supply a Canary for Linux. Also, I understand that versions of Chromium are being built continuously. So, just for argument, by the time an individual has "built the latest" Chromium, newer ones already exist. Re. applying the term "stable" to Chromium, I personally think it's inaccurate and should be avoided. IMO, Chromium isn't for general use; it's meant for testers and developers.

Comment: BTW, a related question: [Can someone explain why Chromium is difficult to build for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/312366/can-someone-explain-why-chromium-is-difficult-to-build-for-ubuntu).

Comment: @EvanCarroll Do you have a progess report on your compiling/building?

Comment: I diasgree with the move to close as a duplicate of [How to install the latest **stable** version of Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/q/89058/25656). OP has not specified **stable** but **latest**.

Comment: For version 30, your answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/317706/147044

Answer (score 10):

At this point, it appears that the [Chromium Project pages](https://launchpad.net/chromium-project) on Launchpad have become inactive and out of date. The last dev, beta, and daily successful builds from this particular project were made about 65 weeks ago(over a year).

Currently, there is a PPA dev build available as well as two Debian/Ubuntu channels(dev and beta ) provided be Google: that provide deb packages for installation. See [The Chromium projects page](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) for additional information.

**Dev channel for Debian/Ubuntu provided by Google**

- [Dev channel for 32-bit Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=unstable_i386_deb)
- To install, run the following command from the command line:

  `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-unstable_current_i386.deb`
- [Dev channel for 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=unstable_amd64_deb)
- To install, run the following command from the command line:

  `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb`

**Beta channel for Debian/Ubuntu provided by Google**

- [Beta channel for 32-bit Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_beta.html?dl=beta_i386_deb)
- To install, run the following command from the command line:

  `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-beta_current_i386.deb`
- [Beta channel for 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_beta.html?dl=beta_amd64_deb)
- To install, run the following command from the command line:

  `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-beta_current_amd64.deb`

**Launchpad chromium-dev PPA**

There is a chromium dev build(>= version 29.0 at this time) available as a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev).

- **Installation from the command line:**

  The latest dev PPA can be obtained by running the following commands from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Altt</kbd>):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
  ```
- **Installation from the Synaptic Package Manager:**

  - Select Settings --> Repositories --> Other Software --> Add and enter: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
  - Select Add source. Next, select the Reload button on the menu to re-index your package list
  - In the Quickfilter field, enter "chromium" and you will see the latest versions of the packages available for installation from this project.
  - Finally, mark the packages that you are interested in, and click the Apply button.

I have not personally tested this build. Take a look at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev) for more details on this PPA.

The last successful build (29.0.1547.0-0ubuntu0ppa3) occurred on 6.26.2013 is available for saucy, raring, quantal, precise, and oneiric.

> *NOTE: Some Chromium features, including Sync, require an API key, which is not included with the packages below.* See the launchpad page for additional configuration instructions.

See here for the stable release:

- [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Always remember that PPAs are provided by the community, you should be aware of the possible risks before just adding a PPA.

Comment: saiarcot895's repo is out of date.