# Chromium 19+ for Ubuntu

Tags: ppa, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

I'm looking for the repository with the latest Chromium 19+ build for Ubuntu because "ppa:chromium-daily/dev for the daily builds channel is not up to date. (The current version is 18)". This isn't maintained anymore.

(The latest update is from January, which of course doesn't looks like daily build, right?)

Update: I'd written some bash script to upgrade cromium http://paste.ubuntu.com/1110824/

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/q/89058/22375)