# How to properly Install chromium from zip and make it the default browser?

Tags: installation, chromium, install-from-source

Since the Chromium PPA is no longer maintained, for those of us preferring to use Chromium over Chrome, we have two options:

1. Build and Install from Source
2. Download either 'beta' or daily builds (in a zip file)

Unfortunately for me, option 1 is overly complicated. I know how to compile most any other applications in Ubuntu but I've never been able to get chromium to build correctly.

I am currently using option 2. In Chromium I have the Chromium Updater installed ([Chromium Updater from Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hcmicnfbmcjhlbdohdmdhfjlbigkcddl)). This gives me quick access to the most recent 64bit versions.

Once downloaded, I install to `/home/myuser/opt/chrome-linux`. From this directory I can run the `chrome` binary. It works perfectly except for the fact that I cannot get it to act as my default browser.

I've tried, as root, installing the binary in `/opt/chrome-linux/` with a symbolic link to the `chrome` binary in `/usr/bin`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work as a non root user.

So my question is - How do I properly install a downloaded Chromium zip build so that it's listed as an option for the default browser?