# How to completely remove firefox so it won't update?

Tags: updates, firefox, uninstall, language-support

I really don't like firefox, so the first thing I did after installation was install chromium as a browser and removed firefox via terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
```

But every time update manager opens it lists language packs for firefox. I can uncheck the package, but it gets rather annoying.

Is there some lingering file somewhere that I need to purge as well?

Comment: No big deal, everyone has a favorite browser. Why not uninstall Firefox from the Software Center instead? Also, you should read [this Q&A about Chromium](http://askubuntu.com/q/177207/12864) so at least you know how updated it is.

Answer (score 15):

Remove the firefox and all the associated language packs with this command

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove firefox
```

It should remove firefox and all language packs for it. The output in my computer is shown below:

```
anwar@edubuntu-lenovo:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

Your output may vary depending on the packages you installed. The important thing is you should see the uninstallation of these packages

```
firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

Using `autoremove` uninstall packages which was required by firefox but is not required now after removing it. Without `autoremove` those packages will be left on system.

`autoremove`: removes any packages on your system that are no longer needed. As an example if I install package A, it might install packages B and C as dependencies. Simply un-installing package A doesn't automatically un-install packages B and C as well, they are left installed. apt-get autoremove searches your system for packages that have been installed as dependencies but are no longer used and removes them.

See [this `apt-get` manual page for more info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot. Tried this first which removed a lot of packages.

Comment: @AvieRose glad to help. Does that solve the problem. if yes, can you consider it to accept :) thanks

Comment: The command you say to use and the command you used in your example are not identical. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal you can list firefox related packages.

```
dpkg --list | grep firefox
```

Uninstall the unwanted packages.

Comment: Thank you. Ran this command after following the answer below, which removed a lot of packages but, then ran this and found that one language pack had been left. Then simply removed the specific package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should work fine

```sh
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove firefox-locale-en unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks xul-ext-webaccounts
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove firefox
sudo rm -rf ~/.mozilla
```