# What's the latest version of Chromium and how can I upgrade my current version to it?

Tags: chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

[launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser) seems to say 18 but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) says Chromium 21.0 was released on 11 May 2012.

I'm currently using version 18 on a 64 bit 11.04 install.