# Active PPA for latest stable chromium?

Tags: ppa, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

I run chromium and used this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/stable
I just realized that it seems to be abandoned and I'm running a quite outdated version of this browser. There have not been any updates since the first of May this year. Do you know of any PPA thats actively maintained?

Thanks, trmpa

(Yes, I know, I could use google chrome but i would like to go with chromium if possible. Building from source is also not a good option. It's not my own machine and I need updates to work reliably without much intervention from the user)