# Why doesn't Chromium updates itself to the latest version, like Google Chrome does?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

Google Chrome, the Chromium release line Google maintains itself, comes with automatic updating in the background.

However, while the [Google Chrome stable channel for Linux](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) (visit from a Linux machine to get the Linux download) currently has version 22, the [Chromium release in the Ubuntu software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/) only has version 20. Even after using it for a while, it does not update itself to the latest version.

I thought Chromium should update itself to the latest dev or beta channel version, but it doesn't even reach the stable channel version, why is this? Is there a way to update Chromium yourself? I can't find a "Check for updates" function in the settings menu.

Comment: See answer nr. 2 here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium

Comment: First, Chrome stable is still at version 21, not 22. Second, Google Chrome for Linux does not have automatic updating the way Google Chrome for Windows does. Updates are via the Update Manager which checks the Google Chrome ppa. Third, the issue of Chromium lagging in version number has been discussed at askubuntu several times. Please use the "Search" box.

Comment: Fourth - we don't want softwares to update themselves because we do have a powerful package management for that.