# X-notifier doesn't work in Chromium Browser

Tags: chromium, email, chrome-extension

It just keeps checking in vain.

[image]

Also cannot import or export data, but get this error

[image]

I use the latest versions of both in Lubuntu 12.04.

**In Google Chrome it works.**

What could it be the problem?

---

**Edit** - following [vasa1](https://askubuntu.com/users/25656/vasa1)'s comment -

running `sudo aa-status` i get

```
apparmor module is loaded.
16 profiles are loaded.
16 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//launchpad_integration
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince//launchpad_integration
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/ntpd
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
3 processes have profiles defined.
3 processes are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient (1562) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (916) 
   /usr/sbin/ntpd (1695) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Comment: I don't use X-notifier but, because it works in Chrome and not in Chromium, is it possibly due to Apparmor? Canonical supplies Apparmor profiles for the Chromium browser, not for Chrome. If you run `sudo aa-status` in a terminal while Chromium is open, do you see the Chromium profile in `enforce` mode? If it is indeed enforced, you could put in "complain" mode just to see if your problem goes away. If it does go away, that would indicate that the profile is preventing X-notifier from reading, writing or executing something it needs. All this is just a wild guess!

Comment: @vasa1: i added in question what i see in terminal. could you comment that please? (don't know what apparmor is etc)

Comment: You don't have a Chromium profile at all. So your problem has nothing to do with Apparmor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [X-notifier blog](http://xnotifier.tobwithu.com/wp/forums/topic/not-working-in-chromium-browser-in-ubuntu#post-1815) says that the latest version of that addon needs version 21.x or later of Chromium, one that at this stage is not in the official sources.

In the future it will be, hopefully.

But this problem might reappear for future versions,as future addons/extensions may keep asking for newer versions of the browser, in which case see unofficial sources or beta and dev versions.

So, see [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/q/89058/47206) (including unofficial ones) and [How do I get the latest (beta and development) version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/q/225930/47206)