# How do I get the latest (beta and development) version of Chromium?

Tags: chromium

Confronted with [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/225569/47206) I found that I need to run a version of **Chromium** that is newer then the one in the repositories in order to use an extension that I want.

Can I get a such new, even latest version?

In Windows I can use beta Chromium portable that is newer than Google Chrome.

How to get that newest Chromium here in Ubuntu?

Related:

- [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default (Using all repos) 13.04 has Chromium version: **28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.13.04.3**

I found the following while searching the PPA list in Launchpad:

**Chromium Beta Builds** - https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-beta (chromium-browser version 31.0.1650.34 as of 2013-11-01)

**Chromium Dev Builds** - https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev (chromium-browser version 32.0.1671.3 as of 2013-11-01)

### API Keys

**Warning:** Google API Keys are not included with these packages as mentioned in both PPA Links. The process of creating them is quite involved and only recommended for developers!

**Do not update chromium-browser from those PPAs if you haven't understood the process below!**

> NOTE: Some Chromium features, including Sync, require an API key,
>   which is not included with the packages below. To use these features,
>   please follow the 11 steps at
>   http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys. Then, open
>   .profile located in your home folder (you will need to see hidden
>   files), and add the following three lines to the end of the file (on a
>   new line):
>
> ```
> export GOOGLE_API_KEY=<api key>
> export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=<client id>
> export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=<client secret>
> ```
>
> Replace what is in the angle brackets (after the '=' sign in each
>   line) with the appropriate value. You will need to log off and log
>   back on for Chromium to use the keys.

### Installation

To add either of them do the following

**Adding Beta PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

**Adding Dev PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

If you already have it installed then simply do a `sudo apt-get ugprade` instead of installing the package again. Your end result should be something like this:

[image]

Now if you want the Trunk version, please see [the answer by Radu](https://askubuntu.com/a/317706/7035)

**UPDATE** - Remember to add the API Keys since when opening for the first time Chromium you will get this:

[image]

And basically all Google services (Like syncing for example) will not work. So follow the How To above about adding the Api-Keys. To open the profile simply type the following on the terminal:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

And then follow what the instructions say.

Know that this PPAs only have **1 person** (The same person) which means this could be a temp solution (Totally depends on the PPA Maintainer).

Comment: The packages from these PPAs were successfully built with 9 (https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-beta/+packages), respectively 8 (https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev/+packages) weeks ago. Also they are maintained by a single person and I think that this decreases the chance that they will be all the time up to date.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Correct. Thanks for pointing me out of the amount of developers on that PPA.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu That is just FUD. These PPAs are being built today and are currently in the build queue and should be finished tomorrow, as the tarballs were released just today. Not sure why that needs to be brought up. It is similar to PPAs like https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium that were maintained by one person and it was never an issue.

Answer (score 6):

According with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/317672/147044), see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/303183/147044) to get a pre-released version of Chromium (if there is one).

Another way, to get **Chromium right off the trunk**, download it from this site: https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ (this site is maintained by the [Chromium team](http://www.chromium.org/)). After you finished to download, to use it run next commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
cd /download_directory
unzip chromium.zip -d /destination_dir
cd /destination_dir/chrome-linux
./chrome --disable-setuid-sandbox
```

More about how to run Chromium from the unzipped folder: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment.

Proof:

[image: trunk Chromium]

As a note, you can use this version of Chromium as a portable version on more Linux systems.

And finaly, another way is to use **Chromium Updater** extension from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-updater/hcmicnfbmcjhlbdohdmdhfjlbigkcddl).

Comment: Do you have any idea why the sandbox is to be disabled?

Comment: @vasa1 Is not necessary. This is what I chose. The answer is in this link: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment.

Comment: Well, I cannot run chrome without disabling the sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

**Chromium PPA status**

At this point, it appears that the builds linked off of the [Chromium Browser pages](https://launchpad.net/chromium-browser) on Launchpad have become inactive and out of date. The last [dev](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/dev), [beta](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/beta), and [daily](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa) successful builds from this particular project were made about 65 weeks ago(over a year).

At least for the dev and daily builds [Does someone know why the Chromium daily package isn't build anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore) the original build machines broke last year and were never restored(per the maintainer micahg).

As far as the [ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium PPA](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium) goes, it looks like the builds had some issues back in April(?) as a result of Google changing the ToS on the use of their Google API keys that have yet to be resolved. I am waiting to hear back from the maintainer on their status.

**New Chromium PPAs available**

Currently, there are two new Chromium PPAs available for dev and beta. I spoke with the maintainter, yesterday on the status of his PPAs, and it appears that he kicked off some new builds within the last couple of hours.

- Here is the [dev build PPA](http://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev) available on Launchpad. - currently at version 29.0.1547.15
- Here is the [beta build PPA](http://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-beta) available on Launchpad. - currently at version 28.0.1500.89 (build is still pending as I write this)

Additionally, there are two Debian/Ubuntu channels(dev and beta ) provided be Google: that provide deb packages for installation. See [The Chromium Dev-channel projects page](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) for additional information. Note that these deb files are branded as Chrome and not chromium, but they do appear to following the versioning as laid out by the [Development Release Calender](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)

The most current build is available directly from the [trunk](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) runs a number of version ahead of that as laid out by the release calender. Note that this needs to be installed manually (See @Radu's answer), and reportedly will require manual updating).

**Launchpad chromium-dev PPA**

There is a chromium dev build(>= version 29.0.1547.0 at this time) available as a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev).

- **Installation from the command line:**

  The latest dev PPA can be obtained by running the following commands from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Altt</kbd>):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
  ```
- **Installation from the Synaptic Package Manager:**

  - Select Settings --> Repositories --> Other Software --> Add and enter: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
  - Select Add source. Next, select the Reload button on the menu to re-index your package list
  - In the Quickfilter field, enter "chromium" and you will see the latest versions of the packages available for installation from this project.
  - Finally, mark the packages that you are interested in, and click the Apply button.

I have not personally tested this build. Take a look at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev) for more details on this PPA.

The last successful build (29.0.1547.15-0ubuntu0ppa3) occurred on 7.09.2013 is available for saucy, raring, quantal, precise, and oneiric.

**Launchpad Chromium-Beta PPA**

There is a Chromium Beta build available as a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-beta).

- **Installation from the command line:**

  The latest dev PPA can be obtained by running the following commands from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Altt</kbd>):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
  ```
- **Installation from the Synaptic Package Manager:**

  - Select Settings --> Repositories --> Other Software --> Add and enter: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
  - Select Add source. Next, select the Reload button on the menu to re-index your package list
  - In the Quickfilter field, enter "chromium" and you will see the latest versions of the packages available for installation from this project.
  - Finally, mark the packages that you are interested in, and click the Apply button.

See here for the stable release:

- [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Always remember that PPAs are provided by the community, you should be aware of the possible risks before just adding a PPA.

Comment: The links you provided are for Chrome, not Chromium, there's a difference!

Comment: Can you explain "*it appears that the Chromium Project pages on Launchpad have become inactive and out of date*"? You can start from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser. Or from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.13.04.3

Comment: @maggotbrain You are confusing [The Chromium Projects](http://www.chromium.org/) with [Chromium Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)).

Answer (score 1):

Canonical seems to have decided to get involved in providing *more recent* Chromium builds, from what I can tell. Previously, keeping Chromium current was up to the Community. You can read about it here:
[Fwd: Fwd: Chromium Updates](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-November/003006.html) and
[New updates for Chromium](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-December/003125.html).

Edit: my personal prejudice for a stable experience, as far as such is possible, is to stay with Chrome stable and not to experiment with Chromium builds.

Development and Beta versions of Chrome can be downloaded as .deb. files [here](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).