# How to get the newest version of a package installed via apt-get?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, okular

Is there a way to install the latest release of a program other than building it from the source?

I know that the packages/applications in the ubuntu repositories are not always containing the most recent versions of programs to ensure best system stability. However, I would like to have a newer version of the program "Okular". They already released one last **October** but it is still not upgraded in the repositories.

Is there a way to get it with apt-get? Maybe adding some other "unstable" repositories or using a special parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Ubuntu repositories are maintained by a group of human beings. Because they need time to check each application for updates and pack them for distribution, they tend to be generally behind the curve. Stability is slightly less important.

To get bleeding-edge versions, you can build them from source or download the package from their site (if they offer one, I see Okular doesn't), but there is a way that you can use apt for certain programs. Launchpad allows users to create their own apt repositories that packages can be downloaded from. Packages downloaded from these are likely to update much faster than the Canonical archives because the developer will update it themselves when they make it.

Unfortunately, although Okular is on Launchpad, it doesn't have this. https://launchpad.net/okular

You might be able to convince them to make one, but otherwise I think activating the pre-released packages, as Radu proposed, is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System settings** > **Software & Updates**, select **Updates** tab and check **Pre-released updates**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just by doing this, I received some upgrades but Okular wasn't part of it. :( I also checked the "For any new version" notification and I am upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 now, before I was still at 12.10! Maybe after this, the new Okular will be available.

Comment: @schrobe Have you tried to get the package from the developer and use dpkg to install it?

Comment: @schrobe You can try also to check **Unsoported updates**. If no results, the only way remain is to do what RGS said (get the package from the developer and use `dpkg` to install it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Wait for that to finish then type in:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

This should install any updated packages which are available.

If you just want to update Okular type in

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update okular
```

Comment: This added Ocular v 0.16.4 on platform 4.10.3

Answer (score 0):

**Okular - KDE**

The Okular is part of the KDE: http://okular.kde.org/

> February 6, 2013: Okular 0.16 released The 0.16 version of Okular has
>   been released together with KDE Applications 4.10 release...

**KDE 4.10.3 is available for the...**

By the Kubuntu.org: May Updates to KDE Plasma and Applications - http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.10.3

> Packages for the release of KDE SC 4.10.3 are available for Kubuntu
>   13.04, 12.10 and 12.04. You can get them from the Kubuntu Updates PPA for 13.04 and from the Backports PPA for 12.10 and 12.04...

The KDE SC 4.10.3 is now in the Ubuntu Proposed and hopefully moving soon to the Ubuntu Updates: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62666-Kde-4-10-3