# How to force installation of incompatible extensions in Chromium/Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, extension

I was trying to install one of my favorite Chrome/Chromium extensions, [Awesome New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgmiemnjjchgkmgbeljfocdjjnpjnmcg?utm_source=askubuntu) (which I have successfully installed and ran on Chromuim for Ubuntu before,) but it says that the extension is incompatible.
I *know* for a fact that it IS compatible (and I want to test it out even if it stopped being compatible.)

I know that with Firefox's Add-ons, you can simply click through to attempt a forcible installation of a supposedly incompatible add-on, but I can't seem to replicate this behavior in Chromium.

P.S., The "About" page says this:
Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678)

I will provide pretty much any other needed details, so just ask if I left anything out.

Comment: The [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-new-tab-page/mgmiemnjjchgkmgbeljfocdjjnpjnmcg/details?utm_source=askubuntu) indicates that "This extension is expanded by widgets, most of which are installed separately." Seems a bit of a complicated extension. Anyway, I visited the site with Chrome **23** and I see the "+Add to Chrome" button. Do you not see this button with whichever old version of Chrome/Chromium you're using? Or do you see the message only after you try to add the extension? Why don't you update your browser? And how did you know ANTP "IS compatible"?

Comment: I know, use, and love this extension, and, like I said, I have used it before on Chroumuim on Ubuntu. The "Add to Chrome button" is greyed out, and there is a yellow box saying "This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled." When installing a Firefox Add-on, you can simply click the button, then tell it that you want to install anyway, but this isn't working here.

Comment: But how do you know whether the same extension has not been modified to be current? In other words, to work with recent browser versions and not Chrome/ium 20? What Firefox does is another matter. Why don't you upgrade to Chrome 23?

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out how to upgrade Chromium... It's a real pain, as the only downloads easily available are either useless source code, or outdated. Right now, I'm looking at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/89058/95681) to try to figure it out.

Comment: YES! THAT ANSWER FIXED IT!!! :D

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to how to forcefully install extensions, or should we just close this question?

Comment: @ændrük It would still be nice to know how to forcibly install extensions in Chrome, let's go ahead and leave this open.