# Is my Chromium browser up to date?

Tags: chromium

I have chromium-browser installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. When interrogated, it claims to be version 32.

```
# chromium-browser --version
Chromium 32.0.1700.107 Ubuntu 13.10
```

**Is this Chromium up to date?**

It may seem obvious that software installed from the repositories will remain up-to-date as long as the system is updated. However, chromium-browser comes from the Universe repository which is maintained by the community.

```
# apt-cache show chromium-browser
Package: chromium-browser
Priority: optional
Section: universe/web
Installed-Size: 142499
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Micah Gersten <micahg@ubuntu.com>, Fabien Tassin <fta@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 32.0.1700.107-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140204.972.1
```

Is Chromium actually maintained? The Chromium project doesn't have any stable versions but Google's Chrome seems to be on version 33 already.

Comment: Chromium 32.0 is the current version of Chromium that is available from the Ubuntu Software Center. For information about why the Ubuntu Software Center doesn't have a later version of Chromium take a look at this answer: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the latest stable version of Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not up to date.

You can see the Chromium release calendar [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar). At the moment Chromium 34 is the current stable release. Also see the [Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org).

As Thomas W. pointed out, in Ubuntu 13.10 the "Universe" repository is fixed. That means they won't have the newer Chromium in 13.10 ever, unless it's backported or put in a PPA.

Unfortunately, the PPAs of the [Chromium Builds](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily) team at Launchpad, which are supposed to offer a variety of stable and beta Chromium builds, seem not to have been maintained for a while.

This means you will have to wait for Ubuntu 14.04.

If you do not want to wait, you can download and install [Chromium Beta](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) manually (beware, it will not be maintained by `apt`). That will be Chromium 35 Beta, then. Unfortunately the Chromium projects don't provide any stable builds for Linux, so if you want the current Chromium 34 you will have to [compile it yourself](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions). You will first have to [checkout the source](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) using git, then switch to the 34 branch. This is slightly involved, so if you want to do that best follow the instructions that I linked to and if you have any particular questions, post them here. :)

Comment: Wrong.  In 13.10, the "Universe" repository is fixed just like Main is.  They won't have the newer Chromium in 13.10 ever, unless it's backported or put in a PPA.  If they want newer Chromium, they'll have to wait for 14.04 to be released.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you for the pointer. You are right of course, and I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I probably should have asked right away, but what are the security implications? Security fixes are not backported either? Am I using a potentially vulnerable browser?

Comment: Security fixes are backported, Chromium is just not updated to a new version. This avoids regression bugs on the one hand and fixes security vulnerabilities on the other.

Comment: @DamnTerminal Security fixes in "Universe" aren't automatic.  Those're user-contributed/maintained patches through a process that is similar to the Stable Release Updates process.  They're "backported" and put in the `RELEASE_NAME`-security repository, but they won't bump your version up to latest.

Comment: @ThomasW can you please explain why LibreOffice which is also in Universe get updates within a release?

Comment: @DKBose maybe you should read through [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions) which cover the SRU process and identifies why some programs are allowed to have updates to their versions beyond just bug fixes.

Comment: @ThomasW. This is quite interesting. Looking at your [second link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions), I see that `chromium-browser` is actually a standing exception to the SRU rule. Does this mean I was, in the end, correct when I speculated that a newer Chromium would be made available sooner or later in the Universe repos?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa probably better to ask the `chromium-browser` maintainers rather than I.  I don't know what the MRE covers, it may only cover tiny microreleases (like `x.x.2` to `x.x.3`) to fix security bugs and such, but... the chromium-browser people, or the Lubuntu team, would know the specifics.

Comment: Currently, Chromium 33 is the latest chromium version, not 34. M34 is on the beta channel, and M35 is on the dev channel. As for maintenance, there is a maintainer who tries to keep up-to-date versions. At the moment, I believe he's focusing on resolving bugs and keeping an eye on M35 (Aura). As for getting newer versions, there are precompiled builds [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?path=Linux_x64/), and I have (two PPAs)[https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895] that track the beta and dev channels.